# Symfony Sonata OneToMany, Sum or Total of a field is not showing in the Admin List

Tags: symfony, one-to-many, sonata

I have 2 entities, Client and Campaign.

```
Client Entity

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Campaign", mappedBy="client")
 */
protected $campaign;
```

+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

```
Campaign Entity

/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="numberOfBid", type="integer", nullable=true)
 */
protected $numberOfBid;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Clients", inversedBy="campaign")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="client_id", referencedColumnName="client_id")
 */
protected $client;

/* Let's say 
Client A has Campaign A, numberOfBid = 1
Client A has Campaign B, numberOfBid = 5
Client A has Campaign C, numberOfBid = 3
Client A has Campaign D, numberOfBid = 4
                Total numberofBid =    13   
 */
```

Problem: How do I get the sum of all numberOfBid and show it as 1 column in the Client Admin List Board? On the method configureListFields, I tried different ways like using sonata_type_model, doctrine_orm_callback, query but still didn't work.

```
Client ID |  Campaign TotalBid
   A      |       13
```

Hoping for your feedback.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: hello! Any feedback or help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you should rename your

```
protected $campaign;
```

in

```
protected $campaigns;
```

cause it's a collection. One client has many campaigns.

To your problem: You could implement a method on your client entity something like this

```
class Client{
...
    public function getTotalNumberOfBids() {
        $i = 0;
        foreach ($this->getCampaigns() as $campaign) {
            $i +=  $campaign->getNumberOfBid();
        }
        return $i;
    }
...
}
```

and add to your list view by

```
protected function configureListFields(ListMapper $list)
{
    $list
    ...
    ->add('totalNumberOfBids');
}
```

The "magic getter" will automatic invoke the getTotalNumberOfBids method.

Note: Dependent on the number of objects holding by the campaigns collection, the summation of the numberOfBids could be slow due to the use of the foreach loop.

Comment: Hi harrow, Thank you! This actually work for me. But may I ask how it automatically invoke or how did ->add('totalNumberOfBids') automatically called the getTotalNumberOfBids? I just wanted to understand it as well.

Answer (score 0):

There are some conventions in symfony that can be found here http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/contributing/code/conventions.html ... so if you want to access a property from your entity and you dont get it explicit by calling it with an leading keyword like "get" or "is", symfony (or maybe a underlying framework) automatic tries to find a method starting with "get" or "has" and so on ... this is comfortable because you dont have to write the get, set, has and so on before your properties to call the getting and setting methods. 
The tricky thing is, that sonata admin bundle doesn't give you an error in the list view if a property isn't found. For example totalnumberOfBids will left your column empty without any error, cause you dont match the camel-case for the part "number". So you should be aware of naming/calling your properties correct or you will end up in a long time of headache ...

Comment: Thank you for the clear explanation. Appreciate the help